# NestJS Kafka Microservice with REST Endpoints

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-fastify

I am new to NestJS and was wondering if its possible to have a NestJS Kafka micro-service with REST Endpoints as well (ideally using Fastify).

I have found the following configuration for both Kafka and for Fastify but it seems like you can only have one or the other in the same service.

```js
// kafka config

const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
      },
    },
  });
```

```js
// Fastify config

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter(), {
    bufferLogs: true,
  });
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to configure both ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application). First configure the HTTP engine:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter(), {
 bufferLogs: true,
});
```

Then you use `connectMicroservices`:

```js
app.connectMicroservices<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
  transport: Transport.KAFKA,
  options: {
    client: {
      brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
    },
  },
});
```

then you call `app.startAllMicroservices()`, and finally you `app.listen(port)`